# Lightdm fails to start xsession

Tags: arch-linux, i3, lightdm, lightdm-gtk-greeter

I switched from xfce4 to i3 a while ago. The first go through, everything worked fine. I then had to reinstall i3 for some reason, and I can no longer enter `i3` through `lightdm-gtk-greeter`. I have to drop into tty2 and manually `startx`.

The greeter launches fine, but then I have a black screen with just a mouse and none of the i3 commands work. Notably, if I uncomment the autologin lines in lightdm.conf, I can boot straight to i3. I do want to have my computer password protected, though.

#### `.bash_profile`

```
#
# ~/.bash_profile
#

[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc

if [[ ! $DISPLAY && $XDG_VTNR -eq 1 ]]; then
  exec startx
fi
```

#### `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

```
#
# General configuration
#

[LightDM]
run-directory=/run/lightdm

[Seat:*]
greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
user-session=i3
session-wrapper=/etc/lightdm/Xsession

[XDMCPServer]

[VNCServer]
```